# JavaScript Hangman game, problem with event listener

Tags: javascript, function, addeventlistener

When a button is clicked and it equals any letter of the answer word, the button should turn green (and show the letter), otherwise red.

The problem seems to be something with the event listener **buttonGrid.addEventListener**(...);

The function checkLetter() works only for the first question/answer, after the first question/answer when a button is clicked both "if" and "else" block run at the same time, and it marks the button as incorrect even if it is the right button, creates unnecessary incorrect guesses and stops the program.

CODE PEN : https://codepen.io/randomname031/pen/gOZvepQ

Here is the function:

```
function checkLetter(spanarray, spanletter) {
    let l = spanarray.length;

    buttonGrid.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
        attempts += 1;

        if (!event.target.classList.contains("not-this")) {
            if (spanletter.includes(event.target.textContent)) {
                // CORRECT
                event.target.classList.add("correct");
                event.target.disabled = true;

                spanarray.forEach((value) => {
                    if (value.textContent === event.target.textContent) {
                        value.classList.remove("hide");
                        score += 10;
                        l--;
                        console.log(l);
                    }
                });

                if (l === 0) {
                    setTimeout(() => {
                        clearGrid();
                        printQuestion();
                    }, 500);
                }
            } else {
                // INCORRECT
                event.target.classList.add("incorrect");
                event.target.disabled = true;
                guesses--;
                incorrectGuess.textContent = guesses;
                score -= 10;

                if (guesses === 0) {
                    endgame();
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I tried every possible way but I couldn't fix it.

1. Adding and removing the event listener
2. Putting the event listener to another function
3. stopPropagation() ~don't know if I used it the right way
4. and also asked ChatGPT, and it made it even worse.

Comment: `event.target.textContent` <-- This may not work as-expected owing to all the whitespace present in a HTML document.

Comment: Where do you define `l` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the function arguments as global scope variables, and pass only the function definition to the addEventListener, otherwise it will create a new event listener for each question since the arguments will differ for each call. Also, with this approach it is sufficient to add the event listener only once:

```
/* DISPLAY QUESTIONS AND ANSWERS */
let spanArray = [];
let spanLetter = [];
let l = 0;


function printQuestion() {
    answer.innerHTML = "";

    let randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * newArr.length);
    spanArray = [];
    spanLetter = [];

    if (newArr.length > 0) {
        question.textContent = newArr[randomIndex].q;
        newArr[randomIndex].a
            .toUpperCase()
            .split("")
            .forEach((value) => {
                let p = document.createElement("p");

                let span = document.createElement("span");
                span.textContent = value;
                spanArray.push(span);
                spanLetter.push(value);

                p.appendChild(span);
                answer.appendChild(p);
            });

        l = spanArray.length
     

        newArr.splice(randomIndex, 1);

        if (newArr.length === 0) {
            endgame();
        }
    } else {
        endgame();
    }
}

function checkSpan(event) {

    const target = event.target

    attempts += 1;

    if (!target.classList.contains("not-this")) {
        if (spanLetter.includes(target.textContent)) {
            // CORRECT
            target.classList.add("correct");
            target.disabled = true;

            spanArray.forEach((value) => {
                if (value.textContent === target.textContent) {
                    value.classList.remove("hide");
                    score += 10;
                    l--;
                }
            });

            if (l === 0) {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    clearGrid();
                    printQuestion();
                }, 500);
            }
        } else {
            // INCORRECT
            target.classList.add("incorrect");
            target.disabled = true;
            guesses--;
            incorrectGuess.textContent = guesses;
            score -= 10;

            if (guesses === 0) {
                endgame();
            }
        }
    }
}

buttonGrid.addEventListener("click", checkSpan);
```

Comment: Please cache event.target to be more DRY

Comment: Igor Moraru,

Thank You for your response, now I see the problem.

All the best.

Answer (score 0):

The primary issue here seems to be that you're attaching a new event listener to `buttonGrid` each time you call the `checkLetter` function. This means that for each new question, a new event listener is added on top of the previous ones. This is why you see both the "if" and "else" blocks executing simultaneously after the first question.

The solution is to refactor your code so that you only attach the event listener once and then use the current game state to determine how to handle button clicks.

Here's a refactored version of your code:

1. **Global Variables**: You should keep track of the current state using global variables.

```js
let currentSpanArray = [];
let currentSpanLetter = "";
```

2. **Update `printQuestion` Function**: Update the `printQuestion` function to set the current state variables each time a new question is printed.

```js
function printQuestion() {
    // ... (your existing code)

    // Set the current state for the question
    currentSpanArray = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".answer span"));
    currentSpanLetter = answer;

    // ...
}
```

3. **Refactor `checkLetter` Function**: You no longer need to pass arguments to `checkLetter`. Instead, it will use the current state variables.

```js
function checkLetter() {
    let l = currentSpanArray.length;

    if (currentSpanLetter.includes(event.target.textContent)) {
        // CORRECT
        // ... (your existing code)

    } else {
        // INCORRECT
        // ... (your existing code)
    }
}
```

4. **Attach Event Listener Once**: Only attach the event listener to `buttonGrid` once, and call `checkLetter` from within that event listener.

```js
buttonGrid.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    // Check if the clicked element is a button and not already disabled
    if (event.target.tagName === "BUTTON" && !event.target.disabled && !event.target.classList.contains("not-this")) {
        checkLetter();
    }
});
```

5. **Remove Event Listener from `checkLetter`**: Since you're now attaching the event listener outside of the `checkLetter` function, you don't need to add it inside `checkLetter` anymore.

With these changes, you'll only have one event listener on `buttonGrid`, and it will handle button clicks based on the current game state. This should resolve the issue of both "if" and "else" blocks executing at the same time.

Comment: Mohammad, 

I edited the code from the previous response, but thank you for explaining the problem step by step.

All the best.